# ListView Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragment

A lista é carregada no Fragment com a seleção do ítem de menu da ActionBar. Contudo, quando eu clico numa tab diferente da que tem o Fragment com a lista, e retorno para a tab com a lista, a lista que estava anteriormente não é destruída. Ou seja, é feita uma nova requisição a API, retornam os dados normalmente e eles são adicionados a lista que já estava lá.

Como corrigir isto?

Meu *Fragment*:

```
public class Fragment1 extends ListFragment {
    List<Notice> result = new ArrayList<Notice>();
    NoticeAdapter adpt;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_notice, container, false);
        ListView lView = (ListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

        JsonArrayRequest jReq = new JsonArrayRequest("http://192.168.1.101:3000/notices",
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                                try {
                                    Notice notice = new Notice();
                                notice.setId(response.getJSONObject(i).getInt("id"));
                                notice.setPicture(response.getJSONObject(i).getString("picture"));
                                    notice.setPublicationTime(response.getJSONObject(i).getString("publication_time"));
                                notice.setReducedDescription(response.getJSONObject(i).getString("reduced_description"));
                                notice.setReference(response.getJSONObject(i).getString("reference"));
                                notice.setTitle(response.getJSONObject(i).getString("title"));
                                result.add(notice);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Falha com a conexão de internet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                        adpt.setItemList(result);
                        adpt.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    }
                });
          Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext()).add(jReq);
        adpt = new NoticeAdapter(result, this.getActivity());
        lView.setAdapter(adpt); 

        return view;
    }
}
```

E *Adapter*:

```
public class NoticeAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private List<Notice> itemList;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

public NoticeAdapter(List<Notice> itemList, Context ctx) {
    this.itemList = itemList;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

public int getCount() {
    if (itemList != null)
        return itemList.size();
    return 0;
}

public Notice getItem(int position) {
    if (itemList != null)
        return itemList.get(position);
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    if (itemList != null)
        return itemList.get(position).hashCode();
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;

    if(view == null) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_layout, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        view.setTag(holder);

        holder.tvId = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        holder.tvDesc = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.description);
        holder.tvPtime = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.publication_time);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    holder.tvId.setText(itemList.get(position).getTitle());
    holder.tvDesc.setText(itemList.get(position).getReducedDescription());
    holder.tvPtime.setText(itemList.get(position).getPublicationTime());

    return view;
}

private static class ViewHolder {
    TextView tvId;
    TextView tvDesc;
    TextView tvPtime;
}

public List<Notice> getItemList() {
    return itemList;
}

public void setItemList(List<Notice> itemList) {
    this.itemList = itemList;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um dos tópicos mais importantes que devemos entender quando se utilizam *Fragments* é o seu [ciclo de vida](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Creating).

O método `onCreateView()` é chamado sempre que o *Fragment* necessita de ser apresentado na tela.
Como você tem o preenchimento da lista nesse método, sempre que muda de tab o método é chamado e a sua lista recebe novos itens.

Esse código tem de ser mudado para um método que seja chamado apenas um vez. O melhor candidato é o `onCreate()`

Altere o seu código para:

```
public class Fragment1 extends ListFragment {
    List<Notice> result = new ArrayList<Notice>();
    NoticeAdapter adpt;
    Context context;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        //Obtém e guarda o context para uso futuro
        context = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Defina aqui o seu request
        JsonArrayRequest jReq = new JsonArrayRequest("http://192.168.1.101:3000/notices",
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                                try {
                                    Notice notice = new Notice();
                                notice.setId(response.getJSONObject(i).getInt("id"));
                                notice.setPicture(response.getJSONObject(i).getString("picture"));
                                    notice.setPublicationTime(response.getJSONObject(i).getString("publication_time"));
                                notice.setReducedDescription(response.getJSONObject(i).getString("reduced_description"));
                                notice.setReference(response.getJSONObject(i).getString("reference"));
                                notice.setTitle(response.getJSONObject(i).getString("title"));
                                result.add(notice);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                Toast.makeText(context, "Falha com a conexão de internet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                        adpt.setItemList(result);
                        adpt.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    }
           });
        adpt = new NoticeAdapter(result, context);
        Volley.newRequestQueue(context.getApplicationContext()).add(jReq);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_notice, container, false);
        ListView lView = (ListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        setListAdapter(adpt); 
    }
}
```

**Edit**

Esta solução só funciona se em vez de *replace* você usar *hide/show* para alternar entre *Fragments*.

<s>Outra solução será declarar um construtor para a classe *Fragment1* e colocar lá o código que faz a requisição.</s>
Má ideia, há alturas em que o *Android* necessita de [criar novas instâncias](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10450348/2556111) utilizando para isso o construtor *default*

Outra solução será testar se a lista `result` está vazia e só fazer a requisição nesse caso:

```
public class Fragment1 extends ListFragment {
    List<Notice> result = new ArrayList<Notice>();
    NoticeAdapter adpt;
    Context context;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        //Obtém e guarda o context para uso futuro
        context = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Defina aqui o seu request
        JsonArrayRequest jReq = new JsonArrayRequest("http://192.168.1.101:3000/notices",
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                                try {
                                    Notice notice = new Notice();
                                notice.setId(response.getJSONObject(i).getInt("id"));
                                notice.setPicture(response.getJSONObject(i).getString("picture"));
                                    notice.setPublicationTime(response.getJSONObject(i).getString("publication_time"));
                                notice.setReducedDescription(response.getJSONObject(i).getString("reduced_description"));
                                notice.setReference(response.getJSONObject(i).getString("reference"));
                                notice.setTitle(response.getJSONObject(i).getString("title"));
                                result.add(notice);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                Toast.makeText(context, "Falha com a conexão de internet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                        adpt.setItemList(result);
                        adpt.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    }
           });
        adpt = new NoticeAdapter(result, context);
        setListAdapter(adpt);

        //Se result é está vazia faz a requisição
        if(result.isEmpty){
            Volley.newRequestQueue(context.getApplicationContext())
                  .add(jReq);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_notice, container, false);
        ListView lView = (ListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        return view;
    }
}
```